# we need to show $|y(t)|\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Could any one help me how to solve this one?

Consider the ODE $$y''(t)+py'(t)+qy(t)=0$$ where $p,q$ are real constants and $p^2-4q>0$.

How do you show That $|y(t)| \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$

Comment: Hint: What is the characteristic polynomial for this differential equation? How does it relate to the long term behavior of your function?

Comment: There are multiple conditions missing here because the result is false. At the very least, you need that $-p+\sqrt{p^2-4q}<0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

Using the characteristic equation, we have: $m^2 + pm + q = 0$. Can you solve for the roots?

We arrive at the solution:

$$\displaystyle y(t) = c_1 e^{-\frac{1}{2} t (\sqrt{p^2-4 q}+p)}+c_2 e^{\frac{1}{2} t (\sqrt{p^2-4 q}-p)}$$

Now, we are given:

$$p^2-4q>0$$

Can you take it from there?

Aside: Are you sure you wrote down all given conditions? The first exponential term is easy.

For the second, we need $\sqrt{p^2-4 q}-p$ to be negative for the limit to work.

Is this clear?

Comment: Well done...Now it's "wait and see"...But your posts are always so inviting for follow-up questions: you always leave room for that...;-)

Comment: @amWhy: I hope to hear back and this poster is pretty regular. Thx! :-)

Comment: @Amzoti I just copied the problem from a question paper, and I have understood upto the expression of $y(t)$ Thank you and I can do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Remember how you'd solve such an ODE. You write down the characteristic polynomial, find its zeros, and construct the solution from those. For each zero $a_k + ib_k$, your solution contains one or more terms of the form $$
  t^{n_{i,j}}e^{a_k t}e^{ib_k t}
$$
From that, it's easy to see that the solution goes to zero for $t \to \infty$ if $a_k < 0$ for all $k$, i.e. if all the zeros lie on the left half of the complex plane.

You thus just have to find out what $p^2 - 4q > 0$ tells you about the ODE's zeros.